# jQuery Make an URL action on Bootstrap Popover Buttons related to PHP dynamic ID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I must to delete a database entry listed using PHP, a foreach loop display the data in a table and instead a delete button that display a Bootstrap popover confirmation, to send the action at the PHP script I will append in the URL the variable delete='ID', so the button on confirmation, handled by a jQuery script will call the URL www.domain.xx/page=xx&delete=ID.

Every bootstrap popover item has an id generated by PHP like delete_1, delete_2, delete_3 etc. so I must to pass this variable to jQuery dinamically.

I'm using this code to handle the popover in PHP:

```
print '<button type="button" id="delete_'. $prodotto[0] . '" data-toggle="confirmation" data-singleton="true" data-original-title="Eliminare ?" data-btn-ok-label="SI" data-btn-cancel-label="NO" class="btn red btn-outline btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-times"> </i></button>';
```

So `$prodotto[0]` return the product ID eg: delete_1

Then the jQuery function will handle the request and do the URL redirection as action:

```
$("#delete_n").on("confirmed.bs.confirmation", function() {
        window.location.href = window.location.href, '?delete=' . n;
    })
```

I must to replace the `n` in `#delete_n` and handle an infinite number possibility, but this number must to use then in the location.href function.

How i can do this without generate an infinite loop and maybe without using JSON calls?

Thanks a Lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to do it the wrong way. May I suggest the following:

1. Instead of using `#delete_id` use a class like `delete-link`, and add a data attribute with the id like:

   `<button class="delete-link other classes here" data-id="'. $prodotto[0] . '"></button>`
2. Use jQuery to catch the class, not the ID, that way it will fire for each of those buttons:

   ```
   $('.delete-link').on(...);
   ```
3. Construct the delete link using data attribute on the button like:

   ```
   window.location.href = '/some-link?delete=' + $(this).data('id');
   ```

In the event function this should be scoped to the button you click.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm trying to use your way that surelly work and is more simple, but there is no redirect to the url and I can't understand why

Here is the complete jQuery function:

        `var UIConfirmations = function() {
        var n = function() {
            $(".delete_prod_link").on("confirmed.bs.confirmation", function() {
                window.location.href = '?page=prodotti-lista&delete=' + $(this).data('id');
            })
        };
        return {
            init: function() {
                n()
            }
        }
    }();`

Comment: And I've changed the HTML of the button according to:

    `<button type="button" data-id="' . $prodotto[0] .'" data-toggle="confirmation" data-singleton="true" data-original-title="Eliminare ?" data-btn-ok-label="SI" data-btn-cancel-label="NO" class="delete_prod_link btn red btn-outline btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-times"> </i></button>`

The class I'm using is `.delete_prod_link`.

Comment: @andreaem can you debug your script with breakpoint or alert to make sure the function is being called

Comment: @JoseRojas I'm trying to use alerts but can't see the alert in jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    UIConfirmations.init();
    alert('0')
});

Comment: Sorry, was not working cause i've loaded the script after all the page, putting the script in top of the page make the script working as expected

Comment: @JoseRojas Thanks for your help!